# "No input source selected" in Region & Language

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

In 18.04, when I open the Region & Language control panel/Settings, in Input Sources, where there should be a list of input sources, instead it says "No input source selected". Even if i attempt to add a new input source by clicking the "+", selecting an input source, and clicking "Add", nothing changes. This makes it impossible to change the keyboard layout. How do I fix this or if it cannot be fixed, how else can i change the keyboard layout?

Comment: Weird. Maybe your dconf database is corrupted. You may want to try: `cd ~/.config/dconf && mv user user.bak` and relogin to find out.

Comment: Thanks that worked!! If you submit this as an answer to the question then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your dconf database is corrupted. To find out, you may want to open a terminal window, run these commands:

```
cd ~/.config/dconf
mv user user.bak
```

and relogin.